# Controller MVC3 link to Folder/Controller/View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, namespaces, global-asax

I currently got a problem with the namespaces I added this into my global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Admin",
 "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
        null, new string[] {"project.Controllers.Admin"}
);
```

Now my controller is being reached when I type into the url localhost/Admin/Controller/*****
Put my controller isn't giving me the right Views. It's giving me the View in Controller/Views. And I want the Views located in Admin/Controller/Views. I tried linking to them directly but thats not going to well. Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ASP.Net 2 or higher, you probably should be adding this Admin section as an [ASP.Net MVC Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Areas are like mini MVC sites with-in separate folders, which should solve your question.

Comment: Totally forgot about this, you are right this is the way to go.